# Почему не вызывается деструктор

Tags: c#

Вроде как, традиционно деструктор выполняется перед удалением объекта, а в C# как я понял этого не делается.

Вот например:

```
        // с помощью new выделили память для объекта и создали объект
        // а, ссылку положили в переменную monkey
        Pet monkey = new Pet("Вася");
        Pet cat = new Pet("Мурка");

        // теперь по идее, ни одна переменная ни хранит ссылку на объект Вася.
        // теперь там где была ссылка на Васю, хранится ссылка на Мурку
        monkey = cat;

        // явный запуск сборщика мусора
        // который по идее должен бы удалить Васю, 
        // ибо ссылки на него в программе нигде нет
        GC.Collect();
```

Разве сборщик мусора не удалил объект Вася? Ведь деструктор не запустился. Как это работает?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В C#

а) нет деструкторов, а есть финализаторы.

б) Вызов метода Collect не гарантирует немедленного освобождения всех ресурсов. Он всего лишь сигнализирует сборщику мусора, что эти самые ресурсы было бы неплохо освободить. Когда он это сделает? Когда сочтет нужным.

в) вы привели не весь код. Что у вас происходит помимо того, что вы указали - неизвестно

Comment: @DreamChild, когда сочтёт нужным? Ну ясно всё :) А в классе Pet кроме конструктора и деструктора который пишет "Удаление объекта", ничего нет. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @dirtez, где вы нашли в C# деструкторы?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/66x5fx1b.aspx
ещё например в книге Г. Шильдта "Полный справочник по C#", страница 149. 

И что по вашему означает ~ИмяКласса(){}?

Comment: @Flammable: есть, это другое название для финализатора: http://ideone.com/s2b5M0

@DreamChild имел в виду, что семантика деструкторов-финализаторов в .NET отличается от семантики деструкторов в C++, поэтому лучше использовать отличающееся название, чтобы не было путаницы.

Comment: @dirtez: Шильдт может и врать (неоднократно был пойман за руку на неточностях и ошибках), а вот с компилятором, да, не поспоришь.

Comment: Вот я в недоумении и спросил, ибо когда-то писал на C++, и думал что delete в C++ это значит GC.Collect() (после удаления ссылки на объект) в C#.

Comment: @dirtez: как и сказано в ответе, `GC.Collect` — это лишь подсказка сборщику мусора о том, что неплохо бы убраться, но не приказ. Обычно сборщик мусора поумнее нас, и без отвлекающих подсказок справляется намного лучше. Например, в случае двух объектов и короткой программы он вообще не будет убираться, т. к. программа всё равно закончится, и память будет освобождена — так зачем же тратить время зря?

Comment: @VladD, я считаю, что финализатор корректно называть именно финализатором.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к правильному ответу [[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild) замечу, что в .NET есть специальное средство для детерминистического освобождения ресурсов (то есть, способ сказать объекту «а вот сейчас отпусти всё, что у тебя есть, и умри»). Это интерфейс `IDisposable`.

(Вот немного информации по нему: [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx), [[2]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P).)

Этот паттерн нужен, например, в случае, когда ваш объект владеет критическим ресурсом: большим куском памяти (например, картинкой), нативным объектом (например, открытый файл, TCP-соединение), или логической блокировкой (например, право писать в разделяемую структуру).

При использовании `IDisposable` после вызова `Dispose` объект освободит ресурсы, но не будет «убит»: его когда-нибудь съест garbage collector (вас не должно интересовать, когда именно).

Comment: >>  специальное средство для детерминистической деаллокации объектов (то есть, метод сказать объекту «а вот сейчас умри и освободи ресурсы»)

Эдак вы совсем человека запутаете. Освобождать память, занимаемую управляемыми объектами, имеет право только GC. IDisposable лишь предоставляет интерфейс для корректного освобождения некоторых абстрактных ресурсов, которые были захвачены управляемым объектом.

Comment: @Flammable: угу, вы правы. Я в последнем абзаце исправился:

> после вызова Dispose объект освободит ресурсы, но не будет «убит»

Comment: @VladD, да, но чуть выше у вас написаны слова <а вот сейчас умри> и <деаллокация>, которые неприменимы к управляемым объектам.

Comment: @Flammable: по поводу деаллокации согласен и исправил, а вот насчёт «умри» — не совсем: после освобождения ресурсов объект считается недееспособным и не должен участвовать в дальнейшей работе программы. Так что для программы он практически умер.